# How to turn JSON nodes into an Array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have to filter portions of a JSON, there are different nodes/sub-nodes and I really need only a portion, for example this is what it may look like:

```
"node1":{         
    "686":{            
        "value1":"686",
        "value2":"M",
        "value3":0
    }
    "687":{            
        "value1":"687",
        "value2":"L",
        "value3":1
    }
    "688":{            
        "value1":"688",
        "value2":"M",
        "value3":0
    }
```

For example I need to extract the `node1` nodes, specifically `["686","687","688"]` what I have tried so far:

```php
$node1values = array_keys((array)$myjson->node1)
```

The response is weird: `* items` consider that I never use PHP regularly, no idea how to get this sorted without having to write a procedure to iterate every possible node.

Comment: You could use `json_decode()`.

Comment: Yes an its not valid JSON.

Comment: Is JSON already decoded or not? You seem to be using it as an object, so I'd expect that what we're seeing here is a part of dump, not actual JSON.

Comment: @El_Vanja it is a part of a dump, really long JSON to post.

Comment: So if you need it as an array, why don't you decode it as an array to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_column()` to get a particular property from each array element.

```
$node1values = array_column((array)$myjson->node1, 'value1');
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/kQokhv)

Comment: when I try $node1values[0] to read the array I get "PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0"

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid, it's missing commas. When I use valid JSON it works: https://ideone.com/kQokhv

Comment: it is a partial JSON

Comment: I understand that, but even partial JSON needs commas between elements.

Comment: I have tested it on a full JSON but got the error mentioned